EntraID Authentication with ASP.NET Core 8 - xml metadata?
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web app. I need to configure authentication with it to authenticate with my organization's Microsoft portal. My IT group created the app in Azure (I have no visibility into this) and sent me a link to a metadata XML file. They said they will need a metadata file back from me as well.
What do I do with this? I'm new to asp.net in general and have not hooked up authentication with SAML2 before. Are there any guides that take you through this? Is there an easy GUI that can walk you through configuring this?

Why SAML and XML? You should be using OIDC...

Not sure. I have no control over what my organization uses. This is just what they told me they need to set it up.

I recommend you ask them to confirm that it has to be SAML - and ask them if they're 100% certain you can't use OIDC - because ASP.NET Core does not have first-party support for SAML - and AAD/Entra has always been OIDC-first (with SAML support being its red-headed stepchild).

Here are answer to your question: There is no GUI to set up the SAML2 auth with your app. you could use the third party library as there is no official package to support this which is Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 and write code to retrieve Metadata XML File. Here are some links you could refer to: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol.

But in my opinion with the new application, it is better to use OIDC which is easier to implement and newer than SAML. for that you just need to configure app registration on azure portal and use Client ID and Tenant ID in your application you set up authentication using OpenID Connect with Azure AD.

Yes this would seem easier to me as well. Do you have any links to examples of how this is done so I can read up and know what to ask for?

@spacerobot here is ample with blazor you could refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/blazor-web-app-with-oidc?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=without-bff-pattern
